# Material UI: how do I use Theme values with withStyles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a component with Material UI. I am using the default theme file (as per here https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/).

I know I can bring in certain values from the theme with `makeStyles` as such:

```
import { makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  something: {
    color: theme.palette.common.black,
  },
}));
```

That works fine.

But how do I use those same values with styled Material UI components? eg:

```
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const StyledBadge = withStyles({
  badge: {
    color: theme.palette.common.black,
  },
})(Badge);
```

I tried replicating the above, eg:

```
const StyledBadge = withStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
```

but this doesn't work.

Would anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Are you just getting a Typescript error?

Comment: @RyanCogswell yeah - that it doesn't like the `;` and expects a `,`. If I swap them it says the reverse.

Answer (score 4):

I tried creating Component withStyles as below and it is working perfectly.

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export const ExpansionPanelDetails = withStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        padding: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}))(MuiExpansionPanelDetails);
```